# Communication in Android between main view and RecyclerViewAdapter with MVVM

Tags: android, mvvm, viewmodel, android-viewholder

I'm trying to architect a screen with a fragment containing a date picker and some basic inputs and a list of items which more inputs. I'll try to exemplify with images:

[image: Model]

and a screen like this:

[image: Screen]

Input Field 1 and 2 is in ViewModel.
The input field N is in the List and it is in ViewModelItem.
And I have some calculations for each item of the list based on the general data. [I don't know if knowing the implementation of the adapter will help anyone, but here is the link.](https://github.com/futurice/freesound-android/tree/master/app/src/main/java/com/futurice/freesound/feature/common/ui/adapter)

Finally, my question is: What is the best way to make this communication between these viewmodels? I Can't separate them in other screens (my client does want this)

The only thing I can think of is making a "global object" and I would hate to do that. I don't know what else, maybe I'm not applying MVVM correctly?